# jQuery Mobile loads content only after I hit refresh

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, refresh, page-init

My jQuery Mobile page does not load content via `$.get` which is bind into `pageinit` event, but does so when I hit refresh (F5), why is that so?

My HTML page `igra.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

 <!-- stili za custom temo, jquery, jquery mobile, phonegap-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/what.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerymobile.css" />
 <script src="jquery191.js"></script>
 <script src="jquerymobile.js"></script>
 <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css" />

</head>

<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="igra">

  <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
   <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="coins" data-   inline="true" class="vibra">347 coins</a>
   <h3>WHAT?</h3>
   <a href="index.html" data-icon="domov" data-theme="a" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content" class="igracontent"> </div>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My `main.js` with jQuery Mobile code:

```
$( document ).delegate("#igra", "pageinit", function() {

 var par = qs["battlefield"]; 

 $.get('igra.php?battlefield='+par, function(data2) {
  $('div.igracontent').append(data2).trigger('create');
 });

});

//parse url parameter
var qs = (function(a) {
 if (a == "") return {};
 var b = {};
 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
  {
    var p=a[i].split('=');
    if (p.length != 2) continue;
    b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
```

In `igra.php` I make SQL query and retrieve some data which I format in jQuery Mobile style and echo it back.

I know jQuery Mobile does not load `head` into DOM in subsequent pages, so `main.js` is also included in `index.html` head which is landing page of my app. All transitions to new pages are by normal ajax querying (I do not prevent default behaviour).

So what happens? When I navigate to `igra.html?battlefield=3` the `pageinit` event does happen but content which I load via `$.get` from php page does not get inserted! If I hit F5(refresh) the content does get loaded into page. Can anybody explain and help? :) Thank you!

Comment: replace `pageinit` with `pagebeforeshow` as `pageinit` fires once. What versions of jquery and jqm are you using? also, replace `.delegate` with `.on`.

Comment: I changed to `pagebeforeshow` and now the page is completely blank, the same with `on` instead of `delegate`. I have jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 and jQuery v1.9.1.

Comment: put your custom code inside body.

Comment: Also I want to know if there is better way to make mobile app with dynamic content other than the way I am doing it? I want to have pages with attributes (category.html?cat=1) which when clicked will load new jQuery Mobile page with content loaded from MySql database via PHP dependind on the attribute (?cat=1) ?

Comment: putting code inside `data-role="page"` div doesn't do much, actually it only causes content to get loaded twice (because events alse fire from `main.js` which got loaded into DOM on the landing page). The problem is not that the `pageinit` does not fire (alert is shown when debugging) or that `$.get` does not return content (it does - also debugged with alert), the problem is that `$('div.igracontent').append(data2).trigger('create');` does not happen, even though div is there, data is there and I enhance markup with trigger. Everything works when I manually refresh page.